# Responsive website not responding over multiple browsers

Tags: html, css

Okay I am having a very serious issue that I have never come across ever before. I cant even figure out the issue.

I made a website which is both fluid and responsive. I usually make my websites first on Chrome and then fix issues in IE and Firefox, along with other browsers aswell.

My website was fully functional on Chrome. I could see it responding to the change in browser width. But when the site was complete and it was time to shift to check issues on other browsers. I was shocked to see it was not responding on any browser other than Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

You can check out the website, http://demos.affixy.com/travelagents/

I am really sorry for forgetting to include the link to the demo site.

Comment: Uzair, we are happy to help, but we are in the dark here. Can you post the error messages that you receive in the other browsers? If you can isolate and post the offending code, we would be best able to help.

Comment: This is about as vague as you could possibly get.  Post some code and we can help...

Comment: As others have said, all we can offer is sympathy unless we can see the site. But it's a really bad idea to wait until the site is finished before checking it in other browsers. Check regularly, preferably at every step, so that you can see problems as they arise and address them then. Waiting until afterwards is making life really hard for yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that everyone, I forgot to include the link to the site, http://demos.affixy.com/travelagents/

Comment: I don't see the problem, your site works fine in both IE10 and FF20. You're missing the mandatory `a img { border:0 }` rule in IE, but that's the only problem I see.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Its a responsive template. But at my end its not responding to any other browser except for Chrome. I have tried on IE10 FF20 and Safari

Comment: Please perform [basic automated QA](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdemos.affixy.com%2Ftravelagents%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibilities based off the limited information...

You have two declarations for iPad media query in your CSS, one for portrait, one for landscape, yet the values of the media query is the same.  Despite that, there is a typo on the media query of both:

You have: `@media ((max-width: 1024px) {`

Should be: `@media (max-width: 1024px) {`

These are on lines 612 and 675 of style.css

Likely Good Guy Chrome is detecting your error and fixing it for you, other browsers are detecting the error and well.. erroring out.

Answer (score 1):

`@media ((max-width: 1024px) {` and `@media ((max-width: 1024px)  {`
 should be changed to `@media (max-width: 1024px) {` and `@media (max-width: 1024px)  {`.  When I deleted those extra parentheses it worked.